# Eclipse Layout Editor Missing Errors

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I just spent two hours battling a stupid typo. I created a RelativeLayout similar to this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <EditView ...
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"/>
    <Button ...
          android:id="@+id/buton1"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"/>
    <Button ...
          android:id="@+id/buton2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the mispelled control names - buton1 and buton2.

Eclipse did not report an error of any sort, it just failed to lay out the controls properly. To make matters worse, running the activity in the emulator did not result in an error, either, just a bad layout.

Is there any way to make either Eclipse or the emulator to report a "missing ID buton1" error of some sort? It's a really frustrating issue to track down - one that could very easily be detected by a computer.

Itay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADT 17 will have a new lint rule to detect this error. (See http://tools.android.com/tips/lint for info about ADT 16 lint rules; there's a duplicate id detector but not one to detect your scenario.)

Comment: so how can sole the error of can't finding resource? there is no mention in link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the ID starting with plus sign, the ID will be created if it does not exist.
If you omit the plus sign in the ID, the ID will be required to define before that.

So, in your case, if you write as below, you will get the "missing reference" error:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <Button ...
          android:id="@+id/buton2"/>
    <Button ...
          android:id="@+id/buton1"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"/>
    <EditView ...
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: While this makes sense, it doesn't work. I get a "No resource found that matches..." error on all the references. If I reverse the order (and define button2, then button1, then the EditView) it works, but I don't want to do that (and, as of Android 1.6, we don't need to do that).

Comment: You can leave the order as it was in your example. But you still need to use the plus sign only in first appearance of `Id` in the file. For example, for your first button the id should be written without the plus sign as it was specified for the `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"` above. So, the correct definition: `<Button ...
          android:id="@id/buton1"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"/>
`

Answer (score 0):

in the button 1 you define the id using + sign in the layout attribute

```
<Button ...
          android:id="@+id/buton1"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"/>
```

as you set above you need to remove just "+" sign from the layout_toLeftOf attribute value

```
<Button ...
          android:id="@+id/buton1"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"/>
```

and one more thing may it's give you error because while interpret time of this xml the button2 was not found may be in this case just write you button2 define above button1 same way into the EditView